# how to use LIMIT in query of MS ACCESS

Tags: sql, ms-access, select, limit

I want to do a paging system using php 
i'am using access for my data base and it doesn't allow me to do a limit in my selected request.

```
SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 10,20
```

I want to add a column in my request so that i can have temporary IDs with successive integer that will allow me to do between condition

```
|id_temp | id  | name |
|   1    | 56  | exmp |
|   2    | 180 | exmp |
|   3    | 193 | exmp |
|   4    | 194 | exmp |
|   5    | 363 | exmp |
|   6    | 500 | exmp |
```

I tried to use TOP as an alternative solution but it only allows me to select the top 10 and not the others. 
Then I took the ID of my elements in order to use between but the problem is that i can not have the same amount everytime in my result. Moreover i have a really limited server and a big request  so I can't use not in.

Comment: Unfortunately, as you've noticed, Access doesn't support this syntax. I'm not sure I'm understanding the question correctly, but my recommendation would be to get a list of just IDs, store those in memory in PHP and then manage the paging in PHP, passing the next 10 IDs to an IN clause for your query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Access does not support `OFFSET`, so what you can do is a trick like this:

```
select top 10 * 
from tablename
where id > (select max(id) from (select top 30 id from tablename order by id ))
order by id
```

it will return the rows from 31st to 40th ordered by id.
Note: never use `TOP` or `LIMIT` in sql without `ORDER BY` because the result is not guaranteed to be what you expect.
If you want that `id_temp` column, you can get it like this:

```
SELECT 
  ((select count(*) from tablename where id < t.id)+1) AS id_temp, 
  t.*
FROM tablename AS t
ORDER BY t.id;
```